# xrdp stops working when Nvidia driver is installed

Tags: nvidia, remote-desktop, xrdp

I installed xrdp on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 19.10 Desktop. It worked fine and I could connect from my Windows computers using Remote Desktop Connection.

I installed the Nvidia proprietary driver on the Ubuntu machine, and after that xrdp seems to have stopped working. What happens is that from the Windows machine I start Remote Desktop and get the xorg login window. I enter my credentials and they are accepted, then the screen turns black for a few seconds then I'm disconnected from Ubuntu and back at the Windows Remote Desktop.

`systemctl status xrdp` returns:

```
Mar 22 13:02:55 Ubuntu-X48 xrdp[5445]: (5445)(139678258698048)[INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
Mar 22 13:02:55 Ubuntu-X48 xrdp[5445]: (5445)(139678258698048)[DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
Mar 22 13:02:58 Ubuntu-X48 xrdp[5445]: (5445)(139678258698048)[INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=5445 connected to X11rdp_pid=5484 X11rdp_uid=1001 X11rdp_gid=1001 client_ip=fe80::fc46:67f1:6c6b:15cd client_port=16520
Mar 22 13:02:58 Ubuntu-X48 xrdp[5445]: (5445)(139678258698048)[DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
Mar 22 13:02:58 Ubuntu-X48 xrdp[5445]: (5445)(139678258698048)[DEBUG] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: chansrv connect successful
Mar 22 13:02:58 Ubuntu-X48 xrdp[5445]: (5445)(139678258698048)[DEBUG] Closed socket 22 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 43128)
Mar 22 13:03:06 Ubuntu-X48 xrdp[5445]: (5445)(139678258698048)[DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 fe80::4652:1f19:fa9b:d930 port 3389)
Mar 22 13:03:06 Ubuntu-X48 xrdp[5445]: (5445)(139678258698048)[DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
Mar 22 13:03:06 Ubuntu-X48 xrdp[5445]: (5445)(139678258698048)[DEBUG] Closed socket 23 (AF_UNIX)
Mar 22 13:03:06 Ubuntu-X48 xrdp[5445]: (5445)(139678258698048)[DEBUG] Closed socket 24 (AF_UNIX)
```

I looked at `xrdp-sesman.log` and was perplexed to see:

```
20200322-18:04:41] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET6 :: port 6010)
[20200322-18:04:41] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET6 :: port 6210)
[20200322-18:04:41] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
[20200322-18:04:41] [INFO ] calling auth_start_session from pid 17127
[20200322-18:04:42] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
[20200322-18:04:42] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
[20200322-18:04:42] [INFO ] /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log  
[20200322-18:04:42] [CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 17160) to exit
[20200322-18:04:42] [CORE ] error starting program C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe for user visitor - pid 17160
[20200322-18:04:48] [CORE ] window manager (pid 17160) did exit, cleaning up session
[20200322-18:04:48] [INFO ] calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 17127
[20200322-18:04:48] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets:
[20200322-18:04:48] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /var/run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_chansrv_audio_out_socket_10
[20200322-18:04:48] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /var/run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_chansrv_audio_in_socket_10
[20200322-18:04:48] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /var/run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdpapi_10
[20200322-18:04:48] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username visitor, display :10.0, session_pid 17127, ip fe80::fc46:67f1:6c6b:15cd:15022 - socket: 12
[20200322-18:05:30] [INFO ] shutting down sesman 1
[20200322-18:05:30] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
hassan@Ubuntu-X48:~$ ls -la
t
```

What does Windows command have to do with anything on the Linux end?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: No, I never did. Gave up on xrdp.